# TesseractOCR didn't work at all

Tags: php, ocr, tesseract

I'm running Tesseract at Linux server, PHP 5.4. I uploaded main class file into classes/TesseractOCR.php, set chmod to 666 on and unfortunatelly it still returning warnings instead of any values from png file.

Here is my code:

```
require_once 'classes/TesseractOCR.php';
....
$tesseract = new TesseractOCR($file);
$tesseract->setTempDir('/absolute_path_to/temp/'); // temp folder have chmod 777
$tesseract->setWhitelist(range(0,9), '-+.'); // i'm trying to recognize phone numbers
echo $tesseract->recognize();
```

Warning:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(/absolute_path_to/temp/366108750.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /absolute_path_to/classes/TesseractOCR.php on line 236
```

I tried many ways with path to temp folder (and also without it), but I still gain nothing. I'll very appreciate any help or suggestion; I tried to google out solution but every one comes to set temp folder, which not helps me.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: does php have the rights to access ALL of the directories in the path? e.g. `/a/b/c/d/e/file.txt` requires that php has access to `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, **AND** `file.txt`. if php doesn't the rights to even one of those parent directories, everything below that point is useless - it's like a "free take one" basket inside a locked bank vault.

Comment: Yes @MarcB, you're right, but I changed absolute path to shorten version (just /temp), and it didn't help. I put manually files in folder, ex. test.conf and test.txt, after running the script those files disappeared, and script didn't return any values :(

Comment: Try it without setting an temp dir.

Comment: @tobltobs - I tried, still the same problem...

Comment: @kacper: what is the error message if you do not specify a tempdir?

Comment: @tobltobs - response from server: Warning: file_get_contents(/tmp/2067089246.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /absolute_path_to/classes/TesseractOCR.php on line 236

Warning: unlink(/tmp/2067089246.txt): No such file or directory in /absolute_path_to/classes/TesseractOCR.php on line 249

Comment: @kacper - My first thought was that you did messed up something with the custom temp dir path. But it seems your php service can't access the /tmp dir, which makes sense security wise. However, I believe this is a php permission problem.

Comment: You're right, but I tried put manually files in temp dir, and then after running script both of them (test.txt and test.conf) disappeared, so probably permission isn't a problem...

Comment: its a very simple class wrapper for tesseract. You can just try in command line tesseract command and see if you have it installed